# Node how to do something after an nested async for loop is completed.

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am (as I commonly have to do) wrestling with the Async nature of Node.

My problem is I am writing a scraping script, that gets some data, based on that data, gets some more data, based on that data gets some more data, and then based on that does a bunch of stuff. My issue is I am I want to do something when all of those processes are complete, but I am at a complete loss of how.

Onto some scope.

```
(function () {
    getData(function (things) {
        things.forEach(function (thing) {
            getOtherData(thing, function (otherThings) {
                otherThings.forEach(function (otherThing) {
                    getSomeMoreData(thing, otherThing, function (anotherThings) {
                        anotherThings.forEach(function (anotherThing) {
                            getEvenMoreData(thing, otherThing, anotherThing, function (somethingElses) {
                                somethingElses.forEach(function (somethingElse) {
                                    doSomething(somethingElse);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}());
```

So I want to do something once this whole process is complete.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Just a note all the 'get' or 'do' method have IO.

Comment: You pass in a callback to the original function and you call it with the final result.

Comment: Use a flow control library like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) to do this and maintain your sanity.

Comment: @jfriend00 the original function already has a callback. getData already has a callback which is the function that loops through to for each.

Comment: So, add a second one that is the completion callback.  You can have more than one.

Comment: Of course, this deeply nested mess should be reworked using either the async library or promises and both would give you better options for knowing when everything is done and getting the final result.  If you tried to do robust error handling on this mess, it would take a ton of code.  That's the real reason I use promises for this kind of thing as it propagates errors through async much better than anything else.

Comment: @jfriend00 How do you have multiple callbacks? if your function executes callback1(); then callback2(); they are both going to be executes async at the same time.

Comment: I don't know what all your functions do, but it's not hard to have your innermost function that has the result call another function with the final results.  You can either hardwire it to call a specific function or you can pass a callback in somewhere at the top level and then call that callback.  What is so hard about calling another function when you have the final result? If you have multiple async things in-flight at one time in this mess, then we can't help you because there's far too little info exposed to rewrite it for you.  The right answer is to pick a better structure (promises).

Comment: @jfriend00 because the final result of one path, after doSomething is completed is not the final result of all paths, after all doSomethings have been called for all thing, otherThing, anotherThing combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using a module to help organize and improve the layout/readability of your code, such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). It contains solutions for common tasks such as asynchronously iterating through a collection or executing a list of functions in parallel or series.

Comment: Do you have any advice on which methods of the async library to use? I looked into the waterfall method but I am not sure if it will work with the loops.